# Regex PCRE capture multiple occurences query string in URL

Tags: regex, pcre, varnish

I am trying to capture multiple occurence of utm tag in a URL and append when re-writing the url. However i just want utm key values and skip others.

This is a sample URL

> `https://example.com/dl/?screen=page&title=SABC&page_id=4063&myvalue=Noidea&utm_source=sourceTest19&utm_medium=mediumTest19&utm_campaign=campaignTest19&utm_term=termTest19&test=value&utm_content=contentTest19`

I tried this:

```
(\?.*)(page_id=([^&]*))(\?|&)(.*[&?]utm_[a-z]+=([^&]+).*)
```

and unfortunately, it doesn't produce the result I expect.

I need to capture PAGE ID and utm tags both, but do not want `test=value`, `myvalue=Noidea` and only want query strings with utm tags.

Expected Result is the URL below:

`https://example.com/dl/page_id/4063?utm_source=sourceTest19&utm_medium=mediumTest19&utm_campaign=campaignTest19&utm_term=termTest19&utm_content=contentTest19`

one group with `pageid=<somenumber/text>`
one group with all utm tags with key and value

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can make regex like this to get group result:

`(?:(page_id|utm_[a-z]+)=[A-z0-9]+)(?:^\&)?`

Comment: Can we group them together? I plan to use them as query string when rewriting the URL  something like this 


https://example.com/dl/page_id/4063?utm_source=sourceTest19&utm_medium=mediumTest19&utm_campaign=campaignTest19&utm_term=termTest19&utm_content=contentTest19

Answer (score 0):

You can instead replace any parameter that *does not* match the desired ones with the empty string. The pattern for this is

```
(?:[?&](?!(?:page_id|utm_[^=&]++)=)[^&]*+)++$|(?<=[?&])(?!(?:page_id|utm_[^=&]++)=)[^&]*+(?:&|$)
```

Here's a working proof: https://regex101.com/r/L5xcl4/2  It has an extra `\s` only so it works on the multiline input in the tester, but you shouldn't need it as you'll be working on a string that contains only a URL without whitespace.